# How to perform simple zooming with calabash-android

Tags: android, calabash

I have a simple application consisting of a custom chart with enabled zooming. What I want to do is to write a test which will perform some zooming of the chart and will check that the app doesn't crash after the zooming. Is that possible (I looked over the performAction method but the only zoom I found was for the google maps) ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your app is made.
You might be able to solve this using recorded touch events.

So record an event, in your steps play it, and after you have played it verify some part of the UI is still active. Then you will know if the app did not crash.